# can`t align buttons to the bottom of sidenav

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a simple site using Django and HTML CSS tailwind but I am stuck at the side nav and I cant align the buttons to the bottom no matter what I try
I can use some static method but I want it to be dynamic

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
<mdaseta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'script.js'%}"></script>
    
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex">
      <aside class="fixed top-0">
          <div class=" h-screen bg-yellow-400 " style="max-width: 80% !important;">
            <a class="navbar-brand max-h-20 text-white mt-1 ml-6" href="#" >
              FUN CODING
            </a>
            <div class="felx flex-col h-full ">
              <hr class="mx-3"></hr>
              <button class="transition duration-500 text-white text-base font-medium p-3 hover:bg-yellow-300 bg-yellow-400 w-full" >Home</button>
              <button class="transition duration-500 text-white text-base font-medium p-3 hover:bg-yellow-300 bg-yellow-400 w-full" >Explore Blog</button>
              <button class="mb-5 transition duration-500 text-white text-base font-medium p-3 hover:bg-yellow-300 bg-yellow-400 w-full ">Store</button>
              <button class="transition duration-500 text-white text-base font-medium p-3 hover:bg-yellow-300 bg-yellow-400 w-full" >Contact me</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      
      <main>
          <div class=" bg-white" style="height: 1000px;" ></div>
      </main>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

by the way this is my first time creating a website and the first time I touched HTML CSS and tailwind
so please don't laugh at that mess

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want them to be on the left sidenav, vertically aligned, but at the bottom, or at the bottom of the page and horizontally aligned?

Comment: first of all you make typo mistake <div class="felx flex-col h-full "> instead of <div class="flex flex-col h-full ">. If you want your items to be aligned to bottom just add justify-content:flex-end; to your flex-col class

Comment: @pierre I want them to be vertically aligned on the side nav

Comment: @Asturion thanks dude fixing the typo made the justify class worked, that was dumb